# CoreData: Fault not firing via to-one relationship

Tags: core-data, relationship, one-to-one, fault

I have three entities:

- `Notification`
- `PlanDate`
- `User`

Relationships:

- `Notification` has to-one relationship with `PlanDate`
- `Notification` also has to-many relationship with `User`

Code:

```
NSLog (@"Selected Object From  Detail ViewDidLoad %@", managedObject);
NSManagedObject *planDateObject = ((PlanDate *)[managedObject valueForKey:@"plandate"]);        
NSLog(@"planDateObject %@", planDateObject);
NSString *recipientUserName = [planDateObject valueForKey:@"recipientUserName"];
NSLog(@"recipientUserName: %@", recipientUserName);
```

Here is the log:

```
2013-08-21 12:26:50.349 Time[5018:c07] Selected Object From  Detail ViewDidLoad <Notification: 0xa58ee70> (entity: Notification; id: 0xb2a5480 <x-coredata://C0FB76AD-19EB-42BA-981A-F99DD6DCF6C7-5018-0000101A36CFA3D1/Notification/p0B2ABAC1-77F3-4F46-B14D-34652F148B37> ; data: {
appType = 1;
invitationType = PlanDate;
lastmoddate = "2013-08-21 17:42:42 +0000";
"notification_id" = "0B2ABAC1-77F3-4F46-B14D-34652F148B37";
plandate = "0xa1c9350 <x-coredata://C0FB76AD-19EB-42BA-981A-F99DD6DCF6C7-5018-0000101A36CFA3D1/Notification/p1C004B2B-F1DA-4EE0-9FAC-0A89E0DBCDB7>";
users = "<relationship fault: 0xb2aa210 'users'>";
})
2013-08-21 12:26:50.350 Time[5018:c07] planDateObject <Notification: 0xb292800> (entity: Notification; id: 0xa1c9350 <x-coredata://C0FB76AD-19EB-42BA-981A-F99DD6DCF6C7-5018-0000101A36CFA3D1/Notification/p1C004B2B-F1DA-4EE0-9FAC-0A89E0DBCDB7> ; data: <fault>)
2013-08-21 12:26:53.406 Time[5018:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Notification 0xb292800> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Notification is not key value coding-compliant for the key "recipientUserName".'
```

There is indeed an attribute "recipientUserName" with a Value.  I have tried other attributes that produce the same log.

Why the error?  Why is the Data shown as fault when I'm trying to access its attribute?

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that there is not actually an attribute named `recipientUserName` on the entity `Notification`. Let's run through your results to see what happened. First you do this:

```
NSLog (@"Selected Object From  Detail ViewDidLoad %@", managedObject);
```

And the result is this:

```
2013-08-21 12:26:50.349 Time[5018:c07] Selected Object From  Detail ViewDidLoad <Notification: 0xa58ee70> (entity: Notification; id: 0xb2a5480 <x-coredata://C0FB76AD-19EB-42BA-981A-F99DD6DCF6C7-5018-0000101A36CFA3D1/Notification/p0B2ABAC1-77F3-4F46-B14D-34652F148B37> ; data: {
appType = 1;
invitationType = PlanDate;
lastmoddate = "2013-08-21 17:42:42 +0000";
"notification_id" = "0B2ABAC1-77F3-4F46-B14D-34652F148B37";
plandate = "0xa1c9350 <x-coredata://C0FB76AD-19EB-42BA-981A-F99DD6DCF6C7-5018-0000101A36CFA3D1/Notification/p1C004B2B-F1DA-4EE0-9FAC-0A89E0DBCDB7>";
users = "<relationship fault: 0xb2aa210 'users'>";
})
```

This says that `managedObject` is an instance of `Notification`, and that `Notification`'s attributes are:

- `appType`
- `invitationType`
- `lastmoddate`
- `notification_id`
- `plandate`
- `users`

The `plandate` attribute is actually a to-one relationship. According to the log message, the object at the other end of this relationship is another instance of `Notification` (as indicated by the `x-coredata` managed object ID representation). I'm guessing you meant this to be an instance of `PlanDate`, but your log message says that this isn't what you actually have there.

Next you do this:

```
NSManagedObject *planDateObject = ((PlanDate *)[managedObject valueForKey:@"plandate"]);        
NSLog(@"planDateObject %@", planDateObject);
```

And the result is:

```
2013-08-21 12:26:50.350 Time[5018:c07] planDateObject <Notification: 0xb292800> (entity: Notification; id: 0xa1c9350 <x-coredata://C0FB76AD-19EB-42BA-981A-F99DD6DCF6C7-5018-0000101A36CFA3D1/Notification/p1C004B2B-F1DA-4EE0-9FAC-0A89E0DBCDB7> ; data: <fault>)
```

So if you had any doubt about what type `planDateObject` is, this nails it. It's most definitely an instance of the `Notification` entity. The typecast to `PlanDate` doesn't mean anything here. The fact that the data is shown as `<fault>` is normal here, because at this point you haven't tried to access any of its attributes.

Finally you do this:

```
NSString *recipientUserName = [planDateObject valueForKey:@"recipientUserName"];
```

You're trying to get the value of the `recipientUserName` attribute. But we already know that `planDateObject` is a `Notification`, and that `Notification` does not have an attribute with that name. So, you get an exception from trying to access a nonexistent key.

So, **if** your `PlanDate` entity has an attribute named `recipientUserName`, then your problem is that the `plandate` relationship is pointing at the wrong object. If `PlanDate` does not have that attribute, you have more complex problems that can't be solved from the information you've provided.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your detailed explanation!  I was just reading your answer at the another SO question.  I was beginning to sense that I'm barking up the wrong tree looking for 'recipientUserName' in 'Notification' entity.  PlanDate absolutely has 'recipientUserName' attribute.  I'm having trouble getting to the plandate Object through notification.  Should I post up screen shots of how I set up the relationship?

Comment: Okay, I updated it with the setup Images. I think I may have set up the relationship wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the inverse relationship is messed up. `PlanDate.notification` looks OK, but `Notification.plandate` is pointing right back at `Notification`. Change that to point to `PlanDate` and fix the inverse relationship setting to point to `PlanDate.notification`.